# Problem, reading date field from visual foxpro dbf file

Tags: excel, foxpro, dbf

when I try to get data from dbf file to Excel PowerQuery, using Visual Foxpro OLE DB provider all is ok except date field - I get 1899-12-30. The same result when I try to do that with C# + OLEDB.
When I just open this dbf file with Excel, instead of date string I see symbols like that:Ü|%
How to read/convert dbf date field correctly?

Comment: Excel has a tendency to corrupt FoxPro tables. Have you tried opening the table in FoxPro to make sure the date field is valid?

Comment: This problem exists for all dbf files I have in application. I do not think all  files are corrupted. And  FoxPro app shows date in proper way. Unfortunately, I do not have FoxPro.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Dec 20, 1899 is basically an empty date is intentional.  Going WAYY WAYYYY back, I can't remember the exact time I needed, but that was like a baseline date within Excel.  When trying to read in dates from Excel, I would have to add the number of days between date() and date(1899,12,30) to get correct date.  It should not be considered a garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was non standard dbf date field format - instead of 8 bytes it takes 4 bytes only (after analyzing with hex viewer). So, Visual FoxPro OLE DB provider could not interpret it correctly.